# Are constants a special case of coefficients?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, terminology

What I hope to understand better, is the relation between constants and coefficients.

Consider the following polynomial:
$$3x^2+2x+5$$
What are the coefficients in the expression? Obviously, 3 and 2 are coefficients, and the 5 is a constant. However, we can think of 5 as being the coefficient of $x^0$. So, is 5 a coefficient or a constant? Or could we say that constants are just a special case of coefficients, namely coefficients that are multiplicative factors of a zero degree variable?

If they are, then how should we identify coefficients, say, on a test? Should we also write out the constants mentioning that they are a special case?

Also, in the case of an expression having more than one variable, e.g. $x^3+y^2+7$, what is 7 the coefficient of, $x^0$ or $y^0$?

Comment: Generally, it is my understanding that $5$ is a constant, and an arbitrary variable raised to the power zero is not considered.

Comment: polynomials of two variables of degree $D$ are of the form $P(x,y) = \sum_{n,k, n+k  \le D} a_{n,k} x^n y^k$ so you can think to $a_{0,0}$ as the coefficient of $x^0 y^0$. note you can also think to $P(x,y)$ as a polynomial in $x$ with coefficients being polynomials in $y$..

Comment: "A polynomial with all integer coefficients" i.e. an element of $\Bbb Z[x]$, must have an integer for a constant (possibly zero).  We do not say that $3x^2+2x+\pi$ is a polynomial with all integer coefficients.

Comment: In terms of the basis $[1,x,x^2,\ldots]$ the constant term is the coefficient of $\,1 (= x^0).\,$ For $\,f(x,y)\,$ the constant term as a polynomial in $\,x\,$ is $\,f(0,y),\,$ and $\,f(x,0)\,$ as a polynomial in $\,y\,$ and $\,f(0,0)\,$ as a polynomial in $\,x,y,\,$ i.e. the coeff of $\,x^0 y^0.\ $